# Invalid cast exception in System.Configuration.ConfigXmlElement

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable, config

I am trying to access one of the section of my 'web.config' file using below code

```
public static string XMLCheck
    {
        get
        {
            var section = (Hashtable)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Default.Framework");
            return (string)section["ConnectionString"];
        }
    }
```

but getting execption as `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigXmlElement' to type 'System.Collections.Hashtable'`  What's wrong here? How to correct
?

Update

```
 <Resources>
      <Resource Uri="resource:Default:CrossDomain" Version="1.0" Id="8ae96c54" IsEnabled="True" Handler="handler:Default:Framework:Resources:Data:Oracle">
        <Properties>
          <Property Name="ConnectionString" Value="Data Source=TESTDB;User Id=TESTUSR;password=TESTPWD;Persist Security Info=false"/>
        </Properties>
      </Resource>
 </Resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the `configSections` entry in your web.config is a `DictionarySectionHandler`:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
  <section name="Default.Framework" type="System.Configuration.DictionarySectionHandler" />
 </configSections>
<configuration>
```

From your updated code, it looks like you're using a library or framework that defines a custom XML structure for its config section. Normally, you would rely on this library to expose the config settings through its properties. If you really want to parse the XML, you could use XPath like the below:

```
public static string XMLCheck
{
    get
    {
        var section = (XmlElement)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Default.Framework");
        var connectionString = section.SelectSingleNode(@"
            descendant::Resource[@Uri='resource:Default:CrossDomain']
            /Properties
            /Property[@Name='ConnectionString']
            /@Value");
        return connectionString.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its `type="Default.Framework.Configuration.XmlConfigurationSectionHandler`..What needs to be updated with this? Thanks

Comment: If your `<Default.Framework>` is just a collection of name–value pairs, then it should be safe to change the type. If it's a custom XML structure, then you need to get it as a `ConfigXmlElement` instance and parse it as XML (e.g. using XPath).

Comment: Thanks.What needs to be updated in my shared code please?

Comment: Can you paste your `<Default.Framework>` element? You can redact the values; we just need to see the structure

Comment: Could you please suggest. I have updated the code in my post..Thanks

Comment: @Lara: Give the above a try. Let me know if its throws any exceptions.